# What are the available libraries within Google Colaboratory?

Tags: jupyter, google-colaboratory

TensorFlow is surely supported, and PyTorch isn't.
I found a non-comprehensive list here.
https://dbsnail.com/2017/10/26/quick-check-of-google-colaboratory

Is there an official list of supported libraries somewhere?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`!pip freeze` shows:

```
absl-py==0.7.1
alabaster==0.7.12
albumentations==0.1.12
altair==2.4.1
astor==0.7.1
astropy==3.0.5
atari-py==0.1.7
atomicwrites==1.3.0
attrs==19.1.0
audioread==2.1.6
autograd==1.2
Babel==2.6.0
backcall==0.1.0
backports.tempfile==1.0
backports.weakref==1.0.post1
beautifulsoup4==4.6.3
bleach==3.1.0
bokeh==1.0.4
boto==2.49.0
boto3==1.9.115
botocore==1.12.115
Bottleneck==1.2.1
branca==0.3.1
bs4==0.0.1
bz2file==0.98
cachetools==3.1.0
certifi==2019.3.9
cffi==1.12.2
chainer==5.0.0
chardet==3.0.4
Click==7.0
cloudpickle==0.6.1
cmake==3.12.0
colorlover==0.3.0
community==1.0.0b1
contextlib2==0.5.5
convertdate==2.1.3
coverage==3.7.1
coveralls==0.5
crcmod==1.7
cufflinks==0.14.6
cvxopt==1.2.3
cvxpy==1.0.15
cycler==0.10.0
cymem==2.0.2
Cython==0.29.6
cytoolz==0.9.0.1
daft==0.0.4
dask==0.20.2
dataclasses==0.6
datascience==0.10.6
decorator==4.4.0
defusedxml==0.5.0
dill==0.2.9
distributed==1.25.3
Django==2.1.7
dlib==19.16.0
dm-sonnet==1.23
docopt==0.6.2
docutils==0.14
dopamine-rl==1.0.5
easydict==1.9
ecos==2.0.7.post1
editdistance==0.5.3
en-core-web-sm==2.0.0
entrypoints==0.3
enum34==1.1.6
ephem==3.7.6.0
et-xmlfile==1.0.1
fa2==0.3.5
fancyimpute==0.4.2
fastai==1.0.49
fastcache==1.0.2
fastdtw==0.3.2
fastprogress==0.1.20
fastrlock==0.4
fbprophet==0.4.post2
featuretools==0.4.1
filelock==3.0.10
fix-yahoo-finance==0.0.22
Flask==1.0.2
folium==0.8.3
future==0.16.0
gast==0.2.2
GDAL==2.2.2
gdown==3.6.4
gensim==3.6.0
geographiclib==1.49
geopy==1.17.0
gevent==1.4.0
gin-config==0.1.4
glob2==0.6
google==2.0.2
google-api-core==1.8.1
google-api-python-client==1.6.7
google-auth==1.4.2
google-auth-httplib2==0.0.3
google-auth-oauthlib==0.2.0
google-cloud-bigquery==1.8.1
google-cloud-core==0.29.1
google-cloud-language==1.0.2
google-cloud-storage==1.13.2
google-cloud-translate==1.3.3
google-colab==1.0.0
google-resumable-media==0.3.2
googleapis-common-protos==1.5.8
googledrivedownloader==0.3
graph-nets==1.0.3
graphviz==0.10.1
greenlet==0.4.15
grpcio==1.15.0
gspread==3.0.1
gspread-dataframe==3.0.2
gunicorn==19.9.0
gym==0.10.11
h5py==2.8.0
HeapDict==1.0.0
holidays==0.9.10
html5lib==1.0.1
httpimport==0.5.16
httplib2==0.11.3
humanize==0.5.1
hyperopt==0.1.2
ideep4py==2.0.0.post3
idna==2.6
image==1.5.27
imageio==2.4.1
imagesize==1.1.0
imbalanced-learn==0.4.3
imblearn==0.0
imgaug==0.2.8
imutils==0.5.2
inflect==2.1.0
intel-openmp==2019.0
intervaltree==2.1.0
ipykernel==4.6.1
ipython==5.5.0
ipython-genutils==0.2.0
ipython-sql==0.3.9
ipywidgets==7.4.2
itsdangerous==1.1.0
jdcal==1.4
jedi==0.13.3
jieba==0.39
Jinja2==2.10
jmespath==0.9.4
joblib==0.12.5
jpeg4py==0.1.4
jsonschema==2.6.0
jupyter==1.0.0
jupyter-client==5.2.4
jupyter-console==6.0.0
jupyter-core==4.4.0
kaggle==1.5.3
kapre==0.1.3.1
Keras==2.2.4
Keras-Applications==1.0.7
Keras-Preprocessing==1.0.9
keras-vis==0.4.1
kiwisolver==1.0.1
knnimpute==0.1.0
librosa==0.6.3
lightgbm==2.2.3
llvmlite==0.28.0
lmdb==0.94
lucid==0.3.8
lunardate==0.2.0
lxml==4.2.6
magenta==0.3.19
Markdown==3.0.1
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
matplotlib==3.0.3
matplotlib-venn==0.11.5
mesh-tensorflow==0.0.5
mido==1.2.6
mir-eval==0.5
missingno==0.4.1
mistune==0.8.4
mkl==2019.0
mlxtend==0.14.0
mock==2.0.0
more-itertools==6.0.0
moviepy==0.2.3.5
mpi4py==3.0.1
mpmath==1.1.0
msgpack==0.5.6
msgpack-numpy==0.4.3.2
multiprocess==0.70.7
multitasking==0.0.7
murmurhash==1.0.2
music21==5.5.0
natsort==5.5.0
nbconvert==5.4.1
nbformat==4.4.0
networkx==2.2
nibabel==2.3.3
nltk==3.2.5
nose==1.3.7
notebook==5.2.2
np-utils==0.5.10.0
numba==0.40.1
numexpr==2.6.9
numpy==1.14.6
nvidia-ml-py3==7.352.0
oauth2client==4.1.3
oauthlib==3.0.1
okgrade==0.4.3
olefile==0.46
opencv-contrib-python==3.4.3.18
opencv-python==3.4.5.20
openpyxl==2.5.9
osqp==0.5.0
packaging==19.0
pandas==0.22.0
pandas-datareader==0.7.0
pandas-gbq==0.4.1
pandas-profiling==1.4.1
pandocfilters==1.4.2
parso==0.3.4
pathlib==1.0.1
patsy==0.5.1
pbr==5.1.3
pexpect==4.6.0
pickleshare==0.7.5
Pillow==4.1.1
pip-tools==3.4.0
plac==0.9.6
plotly==3.6.1
pluggy==0.7.1
portpicker==1.2.0
prefetch-generator==1.0.1
preshed==2.0.1
pretty-midi==0.2.8
prettytable==0.7.2
progressbar2==3.38.0
prometheus-client==0.6.0
promise==2.2.1
prompt-toolkit==1.0.15
protobuf==3.7.0
psutil==5.4.8
psycopg2==2.7.6.1
ptyprocess==0.6.0
py==1.8.0
pyasn1==0.4.5
pyasn1-modules==0.2.4
pycocotools==2.0.0
pycparser==2.19
pydot==1.3.0
pydot-ng==2.0.0
pydotplus==2.0.2
pyemd==0.5.1
pyglet==1.3.2
Pygments==2.1.3
pygobject==3.26.1
pymc3==3.6
pymongo==3.7.2
pymystem3==0.2.0
PyOpenGL==3.1.0
pyparsing==2.3.1
pyrsistent==0.14.11
pysndfile==1.3.2
PySocks==1.6.8
pystache==0.5.4
pystan==2.18.1.0
pytest==3.6.4
python-apt==1.6.3+ubuntu1
python-chess==0.23.11
python-dateutil==2.5.3
python-louvain==0.13
python-rtmidi==1.2.1
python-slugify==3.0.0
python-utils==2.3.0
pytz==2018.9
PyWavelets==1.0.2
PyYAML==3.13
pyzmq==17.0.0
qtconsole==4.4.3
regex==2018.1.10
requests==2.18.4
requests-oauthlib==1.2.0
resampy==0.2.1
retrying==1.3.3
rpy2==2.9.5
rsa==4.0
s3fs==0.2.0
s3transfer==0.2.0
scikit-image==0.13.1
scikit-learn==0.20.3
scipy==1.1.0
screen-resolution-extra==0.0.0
scs==2.1.0
seaborn==0.7.1
Send2Trash==1.5.0
setuptools-git==1.2
Shapely==1.6.4.post2
simplegeneric==0.8.1
six==1.11.0
sklearn==0.0
smart-open==1.8.0
snowballstemmer==1.2.1
sortedcontainers==2.1.0
spacy==2.0.18
Sphinx==1.8.5
sphinxcontrib-websupport==1.1.0
SQLAlchemy==1.3.1
sqlparse==0.3.0
stable-baselines==2.2.1
statsmodels==0.8.0
sympy==1.1.1
tables==3.4.4
tabulate==0.8.3
tblib==1.3.2
tensor2tensor==1.11.0
tensorboard==1.13.1
tensorboardcolab==0.0.22
tensorflow==1.13.1
tensorflow-estimator==1.13.0
tensorflow-hub==0.3.0
tensorflow-metadata==0.13.0
tensorflow-probability==0.6.0
termcolor==1.1.0
terminado==0.8.1
testpath==0.4.2
text-unidecode==1.2
textblob==0.15.3
textgenrnn==1.4.1
tfds-nightly==1.0.1.dev201903180105
tflearn==0.3.2
Theano==1.0.4
thinc==6.12.1
toolz==0.9.0
torch==1.0.1.post2
torchsummary==1.5.1
torchtext==0.3.1
torchvision==0.2.2.post3
tornado==4.5.3
tqdm==4.28.1
traitlets==4.3.2
tweepy==3.6.0
typing==3.6.6
tzlocal==1.5.1
ujson==1.35
umap-learn==0.3.7
uritemplate==3.0.0
urllib3==1.22
vega-datasets==0.7.0
wcwidth==0.1.7
webencodings==0.5.1
Werkzeug==0.14.1
widgetsnbextension==3.4.2
wordcloud==1.5.0
wrapt==1.10.11
xarray==0.11.3
```

You can also use `pkg_resources` to get the list

```
from pkg_resources import working_set
libs = [x.project_name+' '+x.version for x in working_set]
```

For now (Mar 2022), the libs are:

```
['absl-py 1.0.0',
 'alabaster 0.7.12',
 'albumentations 0.1.12',
 'altair 4.2.0',
 'appdirs 1.4.4',
 'argon2-cffi 21.3.0',
 'argon2-cffi-bindings 21.2.0',
 'arviz 0.11.4',
 'astor 0.8.1',
 'astropy 4.3.1',
 'astunparse 1.6.3',
 'atari-py 0.2.9',
 'atomicwrites 1.4.0',
 'attrs 21.4.0',
 'audioread 2.1.9',
 'autograd 1.3',
 'Babel 2.9.1',
 'backcall 0.2.0',
 'beautifulsoup4 4.6.3',
 'bleach 4.1.0',
 'blis 0.4.1',
 'bokeh 2.3.3',
 'Bottleneck 1.3.4',
 'branca 0.4.2',
 'bs4 0.0.1',
 'CacheControl 0.12.10',
 'cached-property 1.5.2',
 'cachetools 4.2.4',
 'catalogue 1.0.0',
 'certifi 2021.10.8',
 'cffi 1.15.0',
 'cftime 1.6.0',
 'chardet 3.0.4',
 'charset-normalizer 2.0.12',
 'click 7.1.2',
 'cloudpickle 1.3.0',
 'cmake 3.12.0',
 'cmdstanpy 0.9.5',
 'colorcet 3.0.0',
 'colorlover 0.3.0',
 'community 1.0.0b1',
 'contextlib2 0.5.5',
 'convertdate 2.4.0',
 'coverage 3.7.1',
 'coveralls 0.5',
 'crcmod 1.7',
 'cufflinks 0.17.3',
 'cvxopt 1.2.7',
 'cvxpy 1.0.31',
 'cycler 0.11.0',
 'cymem 2.0.6',
 'Cython 0.29.28',
 'daft 0.0.4',
 'dask 2.12.0',
 'datascience 0.10.6',
 'debugpy 1.0.0',
 'decorator 4.4.2',
 'defusedxml 0.7.1',
 'descartes 1.1.0',
 'dill 0.3.4',
 'distributed 1.25.3',
 'dlib 19.18.0',
 'dm-tree 0.1.6',
 'docopt 0.6.2',
 'docutils 0.17.1',
 'dopamine-rl 1.0.5',
 'earthengine-api 0.1.301',
 'easydict 1.9',
 'ecos 2.0.10',
 'editdistance 0.5.3',
 'en-core-web-sm 2.2.5',
 'entrypoints 0.4',
 'ephem 4.1.3',
 'et-xmlfile 1.1.0',
 'fa2 0.3.5',
 'fastai 1.0.61',
 'fastdtw 0.3.4',
 'fastprogress 1.0.2',
 'fastrlock 0.8',
 'fbprophet 0.7.1',
 'feather-format 0.4.1',
 'filelock 3.6.0',
 'firebase-admin 4.4.0',
 'fix-yahoo-finance 0.0.22',
 'Flask 1.1.4',
 'flatbuffers 2.0',
 'folium 0.8.3',
 'future 0.16.0',
 'gast 0.5.3',
 'GDAL 2.2.2',
 'gdown 4.2.2',
 'gensim 3.6.0',
 'geographiclib 1.52',
 'geopy 1.17.0',
 'gin-config 0.5.0',
 'glob2 0.7',
 'google 2.0.3',
 'google-api-core 1.26.3',
 'google-api-python-client 1.12.10',
 'google-auth 1.35.0',
 'google-auth-httplib2 0.0.4',
 'google-auth-oauthlib 0.4.6',
 'google-cloud-bigquery 1.21.0',
 'google-cloud-bigquery-storage 1.1.0',
 'google-cloud-core 1.0.3',
 'google-cloud-datastore 1.8.0',
 'google-cloud-firestore 1.7.0',
 'google-cloud-language 1.2.0',
 'google-cloud-storage 1.18.1',
 'google-cloud-translate 1.5.0',
 'google-colab 1.0.0',
 'google-pasta 0.2.0',
 'google-resumable-media 0.4.1',
 'googleapis-common-protos 1.55.0',
 'googledrivedownloader 0.4',
 'graphviz 0.10.1',
 'greenlet 1.1.2',
 'grpcio 1.44.0',
 'gspread 3.4.2',
 'gspread-dataframe 3.0.8',
 'gym 0.17.3',
 'h5py 3.1.0',
 'HeapDict 1.0.1',
 'hijri-converter 2.2.3',
 'holidays 0.10.5.2',
 'holoviews 1.14.8',
 'html5lib 1.0.1',
 'httpimport 0.5.18',
 'httplib2 0.17.4',
 'httplib2shim 0.0.3',
 'humanize 0.5.1',
 'hyperopt 0.1.2',
 'ideep4py 2.0.0.post3',
 'idna 2.10',
 'imageio 2.4.1',
 'imagesize 1.3.0',
 'imbalanced-learn 0.8.1',
 'imblearn 0.0',
 'imgaug 0.2.9',
 'importlib-metadata 4.11.2',
 'importlib-resources 5.4.0',
 'imutils 0.5.4',
 'inflect 2.1.0',
 'iniconfig 1.1.1',
 'intel-openmp 2022.0.2',
 'intervaltree 2.1.0',
 'ipykernel 4.10.1',
 'ipython 5.5.0',
 'ipython-genutils 0.2.0',
 'ipython-sql 0.3.9',
 'ipywidgets 7.6.5',
 'itsdangerous 1.1.0',
 'jax 0.3.1',
 'jaxlib 0.3.0+cuda11.cudnn805',
 'jedi 0.18.1',
 'jieba 0.42.1',
 'Jinja2 2.11.3',
 'joblib 1.1.0',
 'jpeg4py 0.1.4',
 'jsonschema 4.3.3',
 'jupyter 1.0.0',
 'jupyter-client 5.3.5',
 'jupyter-console 5.2.0',
 'jupyter-core 4.9.2',
 'jupyterlab-pygments 0.1.2',
 'jupyterlab-widgets 1.0.2',
 'kaggle 1.5.12',
 'kapre 0.3.7',
 'keras 2.8.0',
 'Keras-Preprocessing 1.1.2',
 'keras-vis 0.4.1',
 'kiwisolver 1.3.2',
 'korean-lunar-calendar 0.2.1',
 'libclang 13.0.0',
 'librosa 0.8.1',
 'lightgbm 2.2.3',
 'llvmlite 0.34.0',
 'lmdb 0.99',
 'LunarCalendar 0.0.9',
 'lxml 4.2.6',
 'Markdown 3.3.6',
 'MarkupSafe 2.0.1',
 'matplotlib 3.2.2',
 'matplotlib-inline 0.1.3',
 'matplotlib-venn 0.11.6',
 'missingno 0.5.1',
 'mistune 0.8.4',
 'mizani 0.6.0',
 'mkl 2019.0',
 'mlxtend 0.14.0',
 'more-itertools 8.12.0',
 'moviepy 0.2.3.5',
 'mpmath 1.2.1',
 'msgpack 1.0.3',
 'multiprocess 0.70.12.2',
 'multitasking 0.0.10',
 'murmurhash 1.0.6',
 'music21 5.5.0',
 'natsort 5.5.0',
 'nbclient 0.5.12',
 'nbconvert 5.6.1',
 'nbformat 5.1.3',
 'nest-asyncio 1.5.4',
 'netCDF4 1.5.8',
 'networkx 2.6.3',
 'nibabel 3.0.2',
 'nltk 3.2.5',
 'notebook 5.3.1',
 'numba 0.51.2',
 'numexpr 2.8.1',
 'numpy 1.21.5',
 'nvidia-ml-py3 7.352.0',
 'oauth2client 4.1.3',
 'oauthlib 3.2.0',
 'okgrade 0.4.3',
 'opencv-contrib-python 4.1.2.30',
 'opencv-python 4.1.2.30',
 'openpyxl 3.0.9',
 'opt-einsum 3.3.0',
 'osqp 0.6.2.post0',
 'packaging 21.3',
 'palettable 3.3.0',
 'pandas 1.3.5',
 'pandas-datareader 0.9.0',
 'pandas-gbq 0.13.3',
 'pandas-profiling 1.4.1',
 'pandocfilters 1.5.0',
 'panel 0.12.1',
 'param 1.12.0',
 'parso 0.8.3',
 'pathlib 1.0.1',
 'patsy 0.5.2',
 'pep517 0.12.0',
 'pexpect 4.8.0',
 'pickleshare 0.7.5',
 'Pillow 7.1.2',
 'pip 21.1.3',
 'pip-tools 6.2.0',
 'plac 1.1.3',
 'plotly 5.5.0',
 'plotnine 0.6.0',
 'pluggy 0.7.1',
 'pooch 1.6.0',
 'portpicker 1.3.9',
 'prefetch-generator 1.0.1',
 'preshed 3.0.6',
 'prettytable 3.2.0',
 'progressbar2 3.38.0',
 'prometheus-client 0.13.1',
 'promise 2.3',
 'prompt-toolkit 1.0.18',
 'protobuf 3.17.3',
 'psutil 5.4.8',
 'psycopg2 2.7.6.1',
 'ptyprocess 0.7.0',
 'py 1.11.0',
 'pyarrow 6.0.1',
 'pyasn1 0.4.8',
 'pyasn1-modules 0.2.8',
 'pycocotools 2.0.4',
 'pycparser 2.21',
 'pyct 0.4.8',
 'pydata-google-auth 1.3.0',
 'pydot 1.3.0',
 'pydot-ng 2.0.0',
 'pydotplus 2.0.2',
 'PyDrive 1.3.1',
 'pyemd 0.5.1',
 'pyerfa 2.0.0.1',
 'pyglet 1.5.0',
 'Pygments 2.6.1',
 'pygobject 3.26.1',
 'pymc3 3.11.4',
 'PyMeeus 0.5.11',
 'pymongo 4.0.2',
 'pymystem3 0.2.0',
 'PyOpenGL 3.1.6',
 'pyparsing 3.0.7',
 'pyrsistent 0.18.1',
 'pysndfile 1.3.8',
 'PySocks 1.7.1',
 'pystan 2.19.1.1',
 'pytest 3.6.4',
 'python-apt 0.0.0',
 'python-chess 0.23.11',
 'python-dateutil 2.8.2',
 'python-louvain 0.16',
 'python-slugify 6.1.1',
 'python-utils 3.1.0',
 'pytz 2018.9',
 'pyviz-comms 2.1.0',
 'PyWavelets 1.2.0',
 'PyYAML 3.13',
 'pyzmq 22.3.0',
 'qdldl 0.1.5.post0',
 'qtconsole 5.2.2',
 'QtPy 2.0.1',
 'regex 2019.12.20',
 'requests 2.23.0',
 'requests-oauthlib 1.3.1',
 'resampy 0.2.2',
 'rpy2 3.4.5',
 'rsa 4.8',
 'scikit-image 0.18.3',
 'scikit-learn 1.0.2',
 'scipy 1.4.1',
 'screen-resolution-extra 0.0.0',
 'scs 3.2.0',
 'seaborn 0.11.2',
 'semver 2.13.0',
 'Send2Trash 1.8.0',
 'setuptools 57.4.0',
 'setuptools-git 1.2',
 'Shapely 1.8.1.post1',
 'simplegeneric 0.8.1',
 'six 1.15.0',
 'sklearn 0.0',
 'sklearn-pandas 1.8.0',
 'smart-open 5.2.1',
 'snowballstemmer 2.2.0',
 'sortedcontainers 2.4.0',
 'SoundFile 0.10.3.post1',
 'spacy 2.2.4',
 'Sphinx 1.8.6',
 'sphinxcontrib-serializinghtml 1.1.5',
 'sphinxcontrib-websupport 1.2.4',
 'SQLAlchemy 1.4.32',
 'sqlparse 0.4.2',
 'srsly 1.0.5',
 'statsmodels 0.10.2',
 'sympy 1.7.1',
 'tables 3.7.0',
 'tabulate 0.8.9',
 'tblib 1.7.0',
 'tenacity 8.0.1',
 'tensorboard 2.8.0',
 'tensorboard-data-server 0.6.1',
 'tensorboard-plugin-wit 1.8.1',
 'tensorflow 2.8.0',
 'tensorflow-datasets 4.0.1',
 'tensorflow-estimator 2.8.0',
 'tensorflow-gcs-config 2.8.0',
 'tensorflow-hub 0.12.0',
 'tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem 0.24.0',
 'tensorflow-metadata 1.7.0',
 'tensorflow-probability 0.16.0',
 'termcolor 1.1.0',
 'terminado 0.13.3',
 'testpath 0.6.0',
 'text-unidecode 1.3',
 'textblob 0.15.3',
 'Theano-PyMC 1.1.2',
 'thinc 7.4.0',
 'threadpoolctl 3.1.0',
 'tifffile 2021.11.2',
 'tomli 2.0.1',
 'toolz 0.11.2',
 'torch 1.10.0+cu111',
 'torchaudio 0.10.0+cu111',
 'torchsummary 1.5.1',
 'torchtext 0.11.0',
 'torchvision 0.11.1+cu111',
 'tornado 5.1.1',
 'tqdm 4.63.0',
 'traitlets 5.1.1',
 'tweepy 3.10.0',
 'typeguard 2.7.1',
 'typing-extensions 3.10.0.2',
 'tzlocal 1.5.1',
 'uritemplate 3.0.1',
 'urllib3 1.24.3',
 'vega-datasets 0.9.0',
 'wasabi 0.9.0',
 'wcwidth 0.2.5',
 'webencodings 0.5.1',
 'Werkzeug 1.0.1',
 'wheel 0.37.1',
 'widgetsnbextension 3.5.2',
 'wordcloud 1.5.0',
 'wrapt 1.13.3',
 'xarray 0.18.2',
 'xgboost 0.90',
 'xkit 0.0.0',
 'xlrd 1.1.0',
 'xlwt 1.3.0',
 'yellowbrick 1.4',
 'zict 2.1.0',
 'zipp 3.7.0']
```

Comment: Is there some more succinct way to think about what this is?  For instance, is it in some way related to the conda distribution?

Answer (score 4):

Most libraries can be installed quickly with a `pip` or `apt`.

### Python 3

To install `pytorch`, add a cell with:

`!pip3 install -q http://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu80/torch-0.3.0.post4-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl && pip3 install -q torchvision`

[Here's an example notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/notebook#fileId=1MeZ5GytPmeav7t8ICYcUkK6qHxzHA13R)

### Python 2

For example, to install `pytorch`, add a cell with the following command:

`!pip install -q http://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu80/torch-0.2.0.post3-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl && pip install -q torchvision`

(Installation should take ~25 seconds.)

To install `opencv`, add a cell with:

`!pip install -q opencv-python && apt -qq update && apt -qq install -y libsm6 libxext6`

[Here's an example notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/notebook#fileId=1zt2EAn01Er-4QCAPwWxB9wybaHeuTh_Q)

Comment: this does not work. it says that the wheel is not supported.

Comment: The invocation is different for Python 2 and 3. I've updated the example.